# Custom button to visualforce page in new window popup size

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button

Salesforce newbie, so bear with me.

I've created a new `button` and added it to a page. The idea is that it pops up a `visualforce` page in a new window. This works, however, I don't seem to have a way of controlling the size of the popup (either directly via the `window.open` call that must be happening somewhere or otherwise).

Do I have to change the `button` behaviour to `onclick` and write it in javascript instead (with my own `window.open` code)? And if so, how would I pass on the correct link to my `visualforce` page to the JS? The page that i'm adding the button to doesn't appear to obviously expose an API towards dumping in links for `visualforce` pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You need to use the window open properties button on the button detail page**

[image]

**This will allow you to set all properties for your popup**

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I've never seen this window due to always clicking 'edit' directly (instead of just clicking on the link for the component) which doesn't show this info. Cheers!

Comment: No prob, glad to help.